# Sql project, edit button not working properly

Tags: sql

[here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ivv5h.png)can you please help me with my sql project. Problem is i have edit button and whenever i select a whole and edit it this change applies to all the date in my table.

Comment: SQL itself has no buttons etc. Which environment are you in?

Comment: it is a project related to database

Comment: I understand. What kind of project? As I said, the SQL language has no such functionality itself.

Comment: You need to tell us more. It seems to be in .NET but we can't guess blindly the solution like that.

Comment: What IDE and programming language is that? The screenshot contains no SQL at all

Comment: a minute please

Comment: Hey, first off add some relevant tags (i guess from your img that it's either C# or VB.NET WinForm/WPF application) 2nd: Add the code behind that is updating the records in your database. Anyways... based on this: 'change applies to all the date in my table' i guess you are just missing condition for ID (primary key) of record you want to update in your SQL command.

Comment: omg i am new into IT and stack overflow too. it is being hard to understand both properly. sorry for inconveniences then

Answer (score 0):

is it a visual basic application that you are running?
please note that in a software you have different layers and parts.
the ui, which is the user interface (front end)
and the back end which is the behind of the scenes of the software / application

behind the back  end, you have the database that holds the data, that's where the SQL comes in hand

what you are showing here is the ui, when clicking on the button, some code runs and queries the database and requests an update.

please share the code or the query itself and we are going to be able to help you.

a quick hint,  when updating,  you need to filter the relevant row for it to be updated; example :
update table
set [column = value]
where (filter)

if the filter is not set, all of the rows of that column will be updated.

Comment: private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dgv.SelectedRows.Count == 0)
                MessageBox.Show("Please select an applicant");
            else
            {
                var c = (Product)dgv.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
                new ProductEditForm().UpdateProduct(c);
            }
        }
here is my edit button code

Comment: thanks :) 
so, assuming that the selectedRows[0] catches the relevant row, you are editing the form and running the edit for the object

you should first debug and see that the relevant row is indeed chosen,

Comment: so what should i change then? i dont know debugging yet

Comment: can i send video here? so that i could fully show u what i have

Comment: but i had a variable c which is being changed and i added update c product there

Comment: thanks :) 
so, assuming that the selectedRows[0] catches the relevant row, you are editing the form and running the edit for the object

correct me if I'm wrong, you first select the row by using its index > selectedRows[0]
then you create a new instance of the product and launch the update function.
note that the entire row will be updated to the "c" object that you are using.

please debug the SelectedRows  Array to make sure that you are pointing to the relevant index. 

in addition, what language are you using? vba?